# Light Inconspicuous Tripod

Tags: tripod

BSD

Does anyone know of any tripod brands that make light think slender inconspicuous tripod. I am basically looking for one with easy mobility that is easy to whip out and shoot on the fly. Also one that doesnt attract too much attention (it just feels weird setting up a shot on a thick luggy tripod with everyone looking at you.) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a monopod? They basically look like walking sticks and are faster to set up than a tripod if you're going to be moving about with it a lot.